# What are the similarities between a beam splitter and a double-slit?

Tags: interference, double-slit-experiment, quantum-optics, quantum-measurements, interferometry

More generally, my question is about the similarity between an $N$-slit and an $N$-mode beam splitter. Conceptually speaking, **would it be accurate to say that the beam splitter is just the discretized version of the slit?** (Let's simplify things and ignore the specific parameters of each such as slit width, transmittance, etc.)

I presume that

> a single particle incident on the $N$-slit delocalizes into $N$ paths
> just as it would if it were incident on the $N$-mode beam splitter.
> One would therefore conclude that the two have the same effect (with
> the only difference that the former is continuous whereas the latter is
> discrete). **(*)**

Where I'm confused, however, is at the measurement stage. For the slit, the measurement would be the pattern formed on a screen, whereas for the beam splitter it would be the clicks on detectors placed at the output modes. I however fail to see how, in this latter case with be beam splitter, one would witness any kind of interference pattern (as is the case for the slit). To see any kind of interference, the beam splitter needs to be followed by a second beam splitter that would recombine the modes (thereby effectively forming an $N$-armed Mach-Zehnder interferometer). Consequently, it would be more accurate to say

> that a slit is actually equivalent to a Mach-Zehnder interferometer,
> and not to a single beam splitter. **(†)**

Something isn't clear in my head as I fail to reconcile the two heuristics **(*)** and **(†)**.

Comment: I think you could deflect one of the modes of a 2N beam splitter with a simple mirror .... back thru the beamsplitter ... that would create interference.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Isn't it a requirement that the field excitations travel in the same mode to witness interference? With just a mirror, the two modes may technically cross but they wouldn't merge (?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's consider a 1 slit experiment ... yes we do see interference as well ... amazing!  Per Feynman we can consider many paths, calculate the sum of phases to each point and voila we get the predicted pattern, and interestingly if we use the Huygens principle we get the same mathematical result.  The Feynman theory (also Dirac, and many others) says that "each photon acts on it own" but I would rephrase this to say "each photon acts on its own within the EM field".  The Feynman calculations (as do the Huygens ones) say the bright spots occur where the path lengths to the spot are multiples of the length of the frequency .... and my interpretation is that the EM field is the cause ... i.e. the EM field resonates, or has wave properties even before the "real" photon travels a path. (The Huygens principle falters as it implies photons are canceling each other on the dark areas .. but not bad of the 1700s).

So when we use the term "mode" the equivalent word is also "path".  And when you use the term "field excitations" (which is very wise) I would say yes it's excitations but that the EM field has virtual excitations (virtual photons) as well as real ones (photons). The problem with the "virtual" excitation is that it sees all paths, i.e. every electron in the apparatus is affected by the excited electron in the source (even before the photon becomes real).

In the 1 beam splitter with 1 mirror example we could tune the arm to be n+1/2 in length ... the EM field would not be "resonant" in this arm per Feynman and no photons would go in that path, if we then tune it to full wavelength then the 50% would travel this path (I'm ignoring phase shifts in the glass that must be taken into account). The problem with this setup is the detector does not know where the electrons have been ... i.e. we cannot see the interference ... maybe we could add a 1/4 wave plate in the arm and use a polarizer at the detector.